# Android Background Bluetooth Processing: What's the best approach?

Tags: android, background-process, android-bluetooth, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I've just develop an Android app (minSdkVersion 23/ targetSdkVersion 29) that can connect to a BluetoothLE device to obtain data periodically.

Now, in the MainActivity (not the first activity), I do the following registering the broadcastReciever:

```
public class StatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    BleService mBleService;
    BleScanCallback mScanCallback;
    BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBroadcastReceiver = new LibBleBroadcastReceiver(this);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter()    
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_DID_WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC);
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_DID_FAIL);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    
        mScanCallback = new LibBleScanCallback(this);
        intent = new Intent(this, BleService.class);
        connection = new LibBleServiceConnection(this);
    
        startService(intent);
        if (!bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("bindService not successful");
        }
    }
    ...
    public void onDeviceDiscovered(String device_address){
        device_connected.activateNotifications(mBleService, connected_device);
        scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                device_connected.requestTemperature(mBleService, connected_device);
            }
        }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
    ...
}
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml it's declared the BleService:

```
<service android:name=".bluetooth.BleService" android:enabled="true" />
```

And then, the user select a device (from a bluetooth scan) and connect to it to obtain data from BLE device.

Once is connected and discovered (services and characteristics), I schedule a task every 30 minutes to obtain data from the device.

All the callbacks that are executed when the device is connected/discovered/dataRecieved are in the StatusActivity not in the BleService (intent) to make changes in the UI (although in the background it would not be necessary).

In the other hand, I have to mantain always a bakground process too, because my app, starts a BLE Advertising to make the phone an LE Device, so always have to be "powered on" to make others devices find the phone.

The problem is that when I put the app in Background or I kill the app this schedule doesn't execute or execute a few times until the process is killed by android.

**What would be the best approach to execute this service in background mode?** Considering that if the app is killed, the device (I think) will be disconnected so I should connect another time to the device (I save the MAC address to reconnect so it's not a problem) and execute the requestData method? **WorkManager/JobScheduler/AlarmManager/ForegroundService**?

Could someone help me to know how to implement and understand the Background lifecycle and how to access all data I need to manage in background?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!! I've another question, I have to mantain always a background process too, because my app, starts a BLE Advertising to make the phone a LE Device, so always have to be "powered on" to make others devices find it. How can i do that ? It's possible? Or i have to try with workmanager every minute (for example)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only working solution for working in Background is ForegroundService, other ones will be destroyed when your device will enter Doze mode. You can find more detailed information in [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/background-ble-scan-in-doze-mode-on-android-devices-3c2ce1764570), it describes all the obstacles in background working while scanning BLE devices.

Comment: Thank you! Doing as ForegroundService is working perfectly :)